# Theme is not appearing in Appearance for multi site in Drupal 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and trying to make multisite using same database, For this i am using `Domain Access` and `Domain Theme` modules. For my default site I am using `/sites/all` folder `theme` and `module` and for another site i have created a folder in the location `/sites/example.com` and also create a `Module` and `Theme` folder and `setting.php` into that `example.com` folder and place the theme & module for the relevant folder.

Now the theme which i put into that directory `/sites/example.com/themes`is not appearing into the Appearance section from back end for the main site. And for the domain site it is showing into the Appearance section. When i enable that theme for the domain site it enabled but after refreshing the main site its again disable for the domain site.

For this condition i did not find that theme into `domain theme setting section`.And if i go to the `Setting` of the `Home/Administration/Appearance` section and select that `example theme` it showing the following error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: example in system_theme_settings() (line 404 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 404 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 442 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: example in system_theme_settings() (line 547 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 547 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: example in system_theme_settings() (line 575 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 575 of /modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: example in system_help() (line 103 of /modules/system/system.module).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_help() (line 104 of /modules/system/system.module).
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i resolve this `theme` issue for create a multi-site in Drupal 7 using `Domain theme` and `Domain access` module??

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to look for:

- Does your theme require a parent theme, or an engine, that might not be enabled?
- Have you cleared the site cache since installing the theme?